# Disable specific section mapping in Vim-LaTeX

Tags: vim-latex

I don't want to disable all the section mappings with `let g:Tex_SectionMaps = "0"` but the SPA -> \part mapping always interferes when I want to type SPARQL. How can I deactivate just this one section mapping?

Answer (score 1):

In `$VIMFILES/after/ftplugin/tex.vim` (create this file if required) add:

```
call IMAP('SPA', 'SPA', 'tex')
```

This creates a new mapping that prints "SPA" every time you insert "SPA", overriding the section mapping.

Comment: I don't have this folder, only `/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/ftplugin/latex-suite/packages/afterpage` and `/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/ftplugin/latex-suite/packages/flafter`. Which of those should I choose?

Comment: Apologies: I think I meant `$VIMFILES`, not `$VIM`. The `$VIMFILES` directory will usually be the `.vim` directory in your home directory, e.g. `/home/konrad/.vim`. Create the `$VIMFILES/after` and `$VIMFILES/after/ftplugin` directories if you don't have them.